# Raise exception in pandas when one column has duplicates but only for given rows

Tags: python, pandas, exception

[image]

I have a dataframe read in from this excel file, if you look at FNCL 2019 and 2018 you'll see that those years (and only the `Vintage` column, not `Bal`) are duplicated. How could I raise an exception to prevent that from happening? It's not that 2019 and 2018 cannot show up multiple times in the `Vintage` column, but rather that, within the FNCL cohort (or any other for that matter), each `Vintage` cannot show up more than once.

Comment: Got it, and `Data1` and `Data2` in this context are what exactly?

Comment: the subset of columns you want to deduplicate, i.e. [Cohort, Vintage]

Comment: Got it, great. What happened to that comment though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways, depending on the expected outcome. If you want to combine the Bal entries for the same cohort and Vintage with a function 'f', then

```
df.groupby([ 'Cohort', 'Vintage' ]).agg( {'Bal':f} ).reset_index()
```

Otherwise, if you just want to drop the duplicates you can use (and keep the first row)

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Cohort', 'Vintage'], keep='first')
```

Comment: Gotcha, the thing is, this is for a script that's supposed to catch these issues so we can fix them, so I actually don't want to delete the rows or do any other transformations, but just raise an exception to notify the stakeholders that it's happening.

Comment: then just check if there are any duplicates, e.g. assert( not (df.groupby(['Cohort', 'Vintage']).Bal.count() > 1).any() )

Comment: What if I just want to see if `Cohort` and `Vintage` are duplicated, but I don't care about all the other columns?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first values are the correct ones, why not simply remove the rest? You can use the following to drop duplicate rows based on certain columns:
`df_unique = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Cohort', 'Vintage'])`

Comment: Gotcha, the thing is, this is for a script that's supposed to catch these issues so we can fix them, so I actually don't want to delete but just raise an exception to notify the stakeholders that it's happening.

Comment: If I understood correctly you're using Python's `with open()` and reading the excel file line by line (as to catch the duplication on the fly) or are you reading it with pandas and just want to know if duplicates exist ?

Comment: Good question, I am reading it in with pandas.